# User Dao to access internal user store in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Im trying to write a customized user signup workflow extension for a WSO2 API Manager(v. 1.8.0). I would like to send a notification email to the admin whenever a user signs up in the api store. In the email i would like to include basic data about the user - email, first name, last name etc...I have difficulty finding out which class I can use to retrieve this data.

Answer (score 0):

Application registration workflow and subscription workflow have DTO classes (ApplicationRegistrationWorkflowDTO.java ,SubscriptionWorkflowDTO.java) where you can cast the WorkflowDTO to them and get the details related to that workflows. But For user signup workflow I couldn't find such DTO class . But as I know when user signup ,all the details of that user will be stored as user profile(which is a feature of IS used in apimanger). So by admin service call you can get the user profile of a particular user.here[1] you can find a sample User profile management service client. Hope this would help you.

1 .https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/platform-integration/test-automation-framework/org.wso2.carbon.automation.api/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/automation/api/clients/identity/UserProfileMgtServiceClient.java

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I solved my question by accessing the user database and getting the data I need. But I know this is the "dirty" way to do it. Using the service client you proposed seems a much better idea. But if I create a new instance of the class, what do I give as parameters of the constructor?What should I put as backEndUrl?

Comment: actually what they have done is, they have used the UserProfileMgtService in UserProfileMgtService.java. So you can write your own client for that service.It is an admin service with in apimager .You can find the wsdl of that service by following this doc[1].

'https://<your-ip>:8280/services/UserProfileMgtService?wsdl'

using that wsld create the stub and invoke the service as you want. you can find the endpoints in the url l.username and password will be the username and password of the supper admin of apimager.

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM160/WSO2+Admin+Services